# How to find out which app uses mdnsd

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

My battery life has dropped massively recently and there's an unrecognised app 'mdnsd' that's using a fair percentage of it.

AFAIK mdnsd broadcasts info about services running to a local network, but I can't think what APIs would need that. How can I find out which app is using this?

Comment: [Why is “mdnsd” draining my battery and how to stop it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213830/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug associated with firefox. From this source: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215012.

It is also suspected to be caused by the patch **Support Multicast DNS** (mDNS)

Further tests showed these results:

```
 Actual results:

Excessive battery usage when using Firefox beta.
Phone Power setting shows MSNSD with increasing usage.
```

This issue was mainly noted in beta version of firefox and version 42.

Several users have complained about the issue and this how they resolved it:

> Install this new version, run it once, and the mdnsd process starts
>   busily running your battery life down. It took my S5 from 17 or 20
>   hours before the battery would run out to 4 hours. This is true
>   whether or not Firefox is running in the background. All the
>   complaints on the web about this start around November 2014 time frame
>   with complaints about the two other random apps, but only a couple,
>   and a comment on the Mozilla Bugzilla platform that there was a report
>   of extreme battery usage sometime in July of 2015

*Source:  [What is MDNSD and how do I get rid of it?](https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/896539)*

Uninstalling firefox proved to be the solution:

> So by uninstalling Firefox, the mdnsd process stopped draining the
>   battery for the rest of the day. After recharging the battery
>   overnight and beginning to use the phone the following day, the
>   Battery usage report no longer shows the mdnsd process!

*Source: [Mdnsd killing battery?](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-5-0-lollipop/605800-mdnsd-killing-battery.html)*

Probably the issue was subsequently fixed with newer versions of the browser.