# Why is "mdnsd" draining my battery and how to stop it?

Tags: battery, battery-life, networking, dns, services

This process (mdnsd) had been draining my battery for a few weeks. I have not been able to find a solution after a lot of search.

I don't have any drone app, Facebook app or Firefox, although it's true the issue started more or less when I installed the Firefox app. But I have uninstalled it, rebooted my phone and the issue is still there which makes me think Firefox maybe didn't have anything to do with this.

Any ideas? I have an LG G2, Android 4.4.2

Comment: How to you see the process list (via an app - which one; or via command-line - adb/termux)?

Comment: @Robert I just see it from the default battery usage feature of my phone

Answer (score 4):

**WHAT IS MDNSD:**

`mdnsd` (Multicast Domain Name System Daemon) is Android's implementation of [mDNSResponder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mdnsresponder/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/README.txt), a part of upcoming *Zero Configuration Networking*. It allows you to automatically discover services and appliances attached to your network:

- Name-to-address translation and other DNS-like operations ([mDNS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)) in the absence of a conventional unicast DNS server:

  > It provides the ability for the user to identify hosts using names instead of dotted-decimal IP addresses, even if the user doesn't have a conventional DNS server set up.
- Network Service discovery ([DNS-SD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#DNS-SD)):

  > It also provides the ability for the user to discover what services are being advertised on the network, without having to know about them in advance, or configure the machines.

This daemon is continuously sending multicast broadcasts (queries / advertisement) to all hosts on local network at IP address `224.0.0.251` and UDP port `5353`, also listening on the same port.

**WHICH APPS USE MDNS:**

Any app that makes use of Android's [Network Service Discovery](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd), will request `mdnsd` running in background <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/core/java/android/net/nsd/INsdManager.aidl#22), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/NsdService.java#56), [3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/server/MDnsSdListener.cpp#561))</sup>:

> Adding NSD to your app allows your users to identify other devices on the local network that support the services your app requests. This is useful for a variety of peer-to-peer applications such as file sharing or multi-player gaming.

A quick search on forums will show many apps being blamed for excessive battery drainage becuase of using `mdnsd`, e.g. ***Facebook*** and ***Firefox***. The later has been gone through a bug in the past that caused the unexpected behavior. Now they have their own implementation of MDNS <sup>([4](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1241368))</sup>. ***Google Play Services*** also have built-in MDNS service (to discover Google Cast receiver devices like Chromecast) <sup>([5](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender), [6](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/discovery#ping_the_devices))</sup>.

> Devices that support NSD include printers, webcams, HTTPS servers, and other mobile devices.

AOSP's built-in apps ***Print Service Recommendation Service*** (com.android.printservice.recommendation) and ***Default Print Service*** (com.android.bips) also make use of NSD. So if you are using printing features on your device, those would be causing `mdnsd` run in background. But the most common reason is ***ADBD*** (Android Debug Bridging Daemon) which force starts `mdnsd` <sup>([7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/daemon/mdns.cpp#43))</sup>.

**HOW TO STOP MDNSD?**

`mdnsd` is an init service <sup>([8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mdnsresponder/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/mdnsd.rc))</sup> which can be stopped by triggers. Add a few lines to `/etc/init/mdnsd.rc`:

```
# stop mdnsd on startup
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    stop mdnsd

# stop mdnsd when adbd starts/stops
on property:init.svc.adbd=*
    stop mdnsd
```

You can also manually stop the service anytime by executing:

```
~# setprop ctl.stop mdnsd
```

Or you can directly kill the `mdnsd` program as suggested by @[DBX12](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213796/218526). The service shouldn't restart because it's `oneshot`. But if it's triggered again and again by some app or the OS, you can make the binary inexecutable (or delete) at all:

```
~# chmod a-x /system/bin/mdnsd
```

However this may break some apps' functionality.

All of the above solutions ***require root***. If your device isn't rooted, the only way is to identify and stop using the app/feature that uses Android's NSD API or directly starts `mdnsd` service.

Comment: I guess I'll have to root my phone. I have tried to identify the app but I couldn't, after playing a lot with uninstalling things

Comment: Did you stop UDB Debugging from Developer Options and restart device? May be it's the ADB starting `mdnsd` at startup. Once started, it won't stop even if you stop ADB later on.

Comment: Yes, I had done that

Comment: May be you have set `persist.sys.usb.config=adb` in your `/default.prop`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it is the daemon for multicast DNS. I have the same issue as OP and Trevor. My solution is the following (assuming you have a **rooted device**). If you have adb, then do step 2 over that, it is more comfortable to type on a keyboard ;)

1. Install a Terminal Emulator
2. Create a shellscript with the content `su -c "kill $(pgrep mdnsd)"`
3. Run it everytime you see fast battery drainage as this is a symptom of a running mdnsd. Confirm the prompt of SuperSU to grant root permissions to the script.

What the script does:

```
su -c "kill $(pgrep mdnsd)"
^      ^    ^ ^
|      |    | |
|      |    | +- Search the process list for the phrase "mdnsd" and return the process id
|      |    |
|      |    +- Spawn a subshell and execute contained command and return its output
|      |
|      +- Stop the process with the process id specified after kill
+- run the command specified after -c with superuser privileges
```

Comment: Needless to say, it requires a working "su" binary, meaning you need a rooted phone.

Comment: @peterh well, I put that requirement in the second sentence in bold ;)

Comment: Oops, thx, dbx! :-)