# How to approach .local addresses in LAN from Android?

Tags: termux

Using .local domains supported by mDNS or Avahi from devices in the same network as my device works flawlessly on macOS, Ubuntu and iOS.
I use it to make http(s) or SSH connection to a device inside the network.
But using a domain like e.g. macbook.local from Android does not work, while it does work from iOS or Ubuntu in the same network.
I have Termux which allows installing Avahi daemon which does allow approaching my Android device from the other devices by androidphone.local (name set in `$PREFIX/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` within Termux). But the other way around still does not work, even from within the Termux environment. I use Android 10 and on the other devices macOS 13, iOS 16 and Ubuntu 22.04.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly the approach uses local DNS server. Are you sure Android does make use of it and not an external DNS server? Check Android network settings if privacy DNS is active, if yes it uses external DNS.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. Android devices are discoverable to other devices on local network through mDNS but not the other way because [Android's DNS resolution process](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218209/218526) doesn't use mDNS. More details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/242004/218526).

Comment: @Robert mDNS is decentralized. It doesn't use a central DNS server. Every mDNS device is a server (and client) in itself.