# Nmap scan result "5353/udp open|filtered zeroconf". Can my device be hacked?

Tags: router, lan

I scanned my Android phone connected to the WiFi router from within the LAN, using nmap. It returned the following result.

```
PORT     STATE         SERVICE

5353/udp open|filtered zeroconf
```

Does this mean if a hacker can somehow get into my router or LAN then they can exploit this port to get into my Android phone?

Nmap command used: `sudo nmap -sSU -F 192.168.1.2`

Comment: Also on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1795064/356789

Comment: `5353/udp` port is used by [MDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS). Many apps and the Android operating system itself uses this protocol for service and device discovery on local network. See more details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213830/218526). MDNS is not very much vulnerable to attacks. See [this](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/network-services-pentesting/5353-udp-multicast-dns-mdns). Also *"a hacker can somehow get into my router"* is not very probable.

Comment: As I understand it, SU doesn't deal with mobile questions.